# Running a PHP with a HTML button click

Tags: php, html

I am setting up a basic webpage that will perform a stress test and simulate a load on my web server.  The stress PHP works, but when I click the button nothing happens.

```
<?php

$urlRoot="http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/";
$instance = file_get_contents($urlRoot . 'instance-id');
$az = file_get_contents($urlRoot . 'placement/availability-zone');
?>
<center>This page was generated by instance <b><?= $instance ?></b> in Availability Zone 
<b>.   <?= $az ?></b>.</center>
<form action="stress.php" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Buy A lot">
</form>
```

Here is the stress php as well

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('stress --cpu 8 --timeout 120 > output.txt &');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I get a file not found and looking at the URL its calling /stress.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style your input like this:
`<input type="submit" value="Buy A lot" name="clickme">`

Than put the following code in your php text outside of any function:

```
<?php 
if(array_key_exists('clickme',$_POST)){
    functionToExecute();
}
?>
```

Put all the stuff you want to execute if the button get clicked in a function, and insert the function-name instead of "functionToExecute".

Comment: does the php text go within website page or the stress.php page?

Comment: `<?php
if(array_key_exists('clickme',$_POST)){
    functionToExecute($output = shell_exec('stress --cpu 8 --timeout 120 > output.txt &');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";)
}
?>` is this what you mean?